# Foreign Key is not Updating

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two(2) tables in a database.

**Student Table:** Student_Id (PK), Name, Last_Name
**Class Table:** Class_Id (PK), Class_name, Student_Id(FK), Teacher_id(FK)

**Note:** The Foreign Key has "ON UPDATE NO ACTION"

This is my query which is not working:

```
`UPDATE Class SET Student_Id = 12 WHERE Class_name = 3  AND Teacher_id = "Pual";`
```

When i run the query the value in Class.Student_id is not updating. It is presently set to NULL. How do i write a query which allows me to UPDATE Class.Student_Id to a value that matches Student.Student_Id?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the definitions of the tables?

Answer (score 1):

can you try this :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
`UPDATE Class SET Student_Id = 12 WHERE Class_name = 3  AND Teacher_id = "Pual";`
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```